# How can I change the anchor point of the UIPopover? PresentFromRect doesn't work correctly for me.

Tags: ipad, ios5

I have looked at several options like:

*http://blog.waynehartman.com/archive/2012/01/07/uistoryboard-on-ios-5-the-good-the-bad-and-the.aspx
*[UIPopoverController Anchor Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481653/uipopovercontroller-anchor-position)
*[Can I change the UIPopover animation anchor point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299482/can-i-change-the-uipopover-animation-anchor-point)

I am trying to show a popover for a map annotation in mapview. For the moment I am using a workaround. I have created a view in my storyboard view controller and anchored my popover to that view. I move the view to the correct location and then load the popover using:

(a) find the location of the annotation

```
CGPoint annotationPoint = [_mapView    convertCoordinate:self.selectedAnnotationView.annotation.coordinate toPointToView:_mapView];
float boxDY= annotationPoint.y;
float boxDX= annotationPoint.x;
CGRect box = CGRectMake(boxDX,boxDY,1,1);
```

(b) move the view (anchorView) that I created in the storyboard to the annotation location

```
anchorView.frame = box;
```

(c) show the popover

```
[annotationPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:box inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
```

My gut feeling is that this workaround is not needed. Is there a simpler and more elegant way to do this?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582564/how-do-i-display-a-uipopoverview-as-a-annotation-to-the-map-view-ipad/5583505#5583505) helps.

Comment: Thanks Anna.

I was using segues to launch the popover - therefore I couldn't position the popover correctly.  
<br\>
I believe that the workaround I used is appropriate for positioning the popover if you are using segues.  

Having said that, I am now using the method suggested by your answer.  

`self.detailsPopover = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifierName"]; `
  
Cheers,  
Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Anna. Apologies for the duplicate posting - had a bit of trouble with the Stackoverflow markup.

I was using segues to launch the popover - therefore I couldn't position the popover correctly.

I believe that the workaround I used is appropriate for positioning the popover if you are using segues.

Having said that, I am now using the method suggested by your answer.

I launch the popover using

```
self.detailsPopover = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifierName"];

//... config code for the popover 

UIPopoverController *pc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailsPopover];

//... store popover view controller in an ivar

[self.annotationPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:selectedAnnotationView.bounds inView:selectedAnnotationView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar answer using a table and a dynamic anchor point. In my solution you can preserve the flow of your storyboard using segues. You would have to adapt the answer a little bit, but basically the same.

[Is it possible to perform a Popover Segue manually (from dynamic UITableView cell)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845508/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-popover-segue-manually-from-dynamic-uitableview-cel/14514837#14514837)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
        case "popover":
            if let vc = segue.destination as? MyTemplateTableViewController, let ppc = vc.popoverPresentationController {
                ppc.permittedArrowDirections = .up
                ppc.delegate = self
// set the sourceRect and sourceView to move the anchor point
                ppc.sourceRect = ((sender as? UITextField)?.frame)!
                ppc.sourceView = sender as? UITextField

            }
            break
        default:
            break

        }
        }
    }
```